# Update grid with added record from AJAX Post, MVC 5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-bootgrid

I've seen quite a few posts on this, but I wanted to try to get a best practice down before going down the route I think I will likely need to go. I'm attempting to update my view after I've inserted a new record into the database:

Pretty basic set-up:

```
<table id="grid-basic" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="role_id">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="description">Description</th>
            <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                <div id="add-role-text-group" class="form-group">
                    <input id="add-role-text" type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Add Role" data-container="body" title="A role description must be entered."/>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default command-add"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

My C# code

```
// GET: Application Role Management
        [Route("role")]
        public ActionResult Role()
        {
            return View(RoleManager.Roles.ToList<IdentityRole>());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("addrole")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddRole(string description)
        {
            IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
            role.Name = description;

            var result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("role");
            } else {
                return RedirectToAction("Error");
            }
        }
```

AJAX POST

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "@Url.Action("AddRole")", // the method we are calling
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({ description: $element.val() }),
     dataType: "json"
});
```

I load the View, grab all the roles in the system and display into a grid. I have an inline row for insertion of a new role. I type in the new role, click a plus button. It POSTs to the AddRole route. How can I now update the model and update the grid?

From what I've seen, I need to run the insert, grab all the roles again, and update the grid in the "success" event. Is this true? Or is there a more conventional, MVC means to doing this via ASP.net? Obviously, I could go down the path of using Knockout or something to that extent, but I'm wondering if there is a means to updating the view this way.

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin for your table?

Comment: Using bootgrid - https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid

Comment: Not familiar with bootgrid, but the [documentation](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#methods) appears to have an `append` method which I assume is for adding new rows

Comment: I'm asking if there is a means to updating the model from the server side. I'm redirecting to load the view again and nothing happens. I assume that's because I've done that in a POST and that can't happen. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Your edit shows your using ajax to post so `return RedirectToAction()` in your POST method is pointless (ajax calls do not redirect) and in any case you have specified `dataType: "json"`. Change your method to `return Json(...);` (you probably want to return the ID of the role you just created?). You already know the `description` so you should be able to use the bootgrid  `append()` method to add a new row based on the returned ID and the value of the textbox.

Comment: I was aware this was likely the case, so I thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST method is attempting to redirect to another action method, but ajax calls do not redirect. Change you method to return the new roles `Id` value and return it to the view as json

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("addrole")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddRole(string description)
{
  IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
  role.Name = description;
  var result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
    return Json(role.Id);
  } else {
    return Json(null);
  }
}
```

Then modify your ajax to add the new role in the success callback based on the value of the textbox and the returned Id value

```
var description = $('#add-role-text').val();
var url = '@Url.Action("AddRole")';
var table = $('#grid-basic');
$.post(url, { description: description }, function(id) {
  if (!id) { 
    // oops 
    return;
  }
  var newRow = [{ role_id: id, description: description }];
  table.bootgrid("append", newRow);
}).fail(function() {
  // oops - display error message?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the current page after adding the role you can do one thing,

add success function in ajax call and put like below

```js
success:function(){
     window.location.href ="your current page url"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use

```
return Json(role.Id,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and then in your ajax call say...

```
success:function(data){
 if(data.Id>0){
  $("#grid-basic").append('<tr><td>data.Id</td><td>//description comes here</td></tr>');
 }
 else{
  alert("error");
 }
}
```

If it is about updating the table then you can either append a row to the table
     the above way or you can reload page or else you can return a partial view and then append it to the div. It is preferred to return a Json and then append the above way.

Comment: Because OP is using Bootgrid. This just adds the html for a new row and does not ad all the other necessary data used by Bootgrid (for searching, sorting etc) Bootgrid  has a specific `append()` method for adding new rows (see my answer). And you have not indicated how to add the description.